# AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

I am getting the following error in Django when upgrading from 1.6.2 to 1.8.3-

```
Internal Server Error: /api/v1/users/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/test/virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 223, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/Users/test/virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 31, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options', None) is not None:
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'get'
[21/Jul/2015 06:44:55]"POST /api/v1/users/ HTTP/1.1" 500 69466
```

Middlewares order-

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)
```

The response type is django.http.HttpResponse and I checked the code, it does have a `get` method. Not sure why I am getting this.
I am using `tastypie` to return a json back, but that shouldn't be a problem because it is converted into a `Response` object.

Comment: somehow middleware_method(request, response) is returning None ? try to print type(response), I am sure it's not response object.

Comment: @NIleshSharma: Close enough guess. Its not `None`, its `requests.models.Response`. Need to figure out the cause for this now. Thanks!

Comment: @Devang, what was the solution? Is it a Django bug or something to do with tastypie's create_response?

Comment: @bad_keypoints - it had to do with another module (django-allauth) that I was using that was sending a different requests.models.Response that tastypie could not serialize. Fix was to catch allauth's error

Comment: @Devang same here. It had to do something with a third party error bubbling up into something else. I too had to catch it.