# Django - django-mailgun Attribute error

Tags: python, django, python-requests, mailgun

When sending an email with mailgun to myself after submitting the email it throws this error:
`Attribute Error: 'Response' object has no attribute 'get'`

In terminal:

```
response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/Users/Kyle/Documents/MyProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 31, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Despite the error, I still receive the email, it just shows the error in the browser afterwards.

This is the same error as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532134/attributeerror-response-object-has-no-attribute-get). However I've been through the mailgun code and can't see where it's going wrong.

I have all the default configurations of mailgun.

Am running:
python 2.7, django 1.9, mailgun 0.8.0, requests 2.9.1

Comment: Are there any other Django apps such as django-allauth?

Comment: @Selcuk Yes, there is allauth, that was running fine before adding django-mailgun